# How to extract specified segments from a scanned document using machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I was using tensorflow object detection api to train images. And it was successful detecting the labeled objects.
Now I want the same concept to be implemented in text extraction. Using deep learning how can I extract information from a document. For example , extracting experience section from a resume. I can create data set for experience, and train them.
1. I wanna know  how can I use this trained model to extract content from a resume?

2. Is there any method available for extracting specified information from  a **scanned document** ?
3. And how to implement machine learning concept in this method?

If my logic is wrong. please help me figure it out.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. We are here to answer specific programming problems. In it's current form, your question is very broad and could be opinion based. I would recommend reading about clustering and topic modelling which have good resources available on other websites. When you've done that, tried some code and face a problem, come back and ask a specific question. :)

Comment: Some relevant links: [topic modelling](https://towardsdatascience.com/topic-modelling-in-python-with-nltk-and-gensim-4ef03213cd21) [document clustering](http://brandonrose.org/clustering)

Comment: what you need is a text categorisation or tagging depending on the content of the scrapped papers. look for python's `nltk.tag`.

Comment: I've documents with different sections, is there any method available for grouping different sections of a document.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Kaggle is the best place to look at for datasets of a kind.

Check [this](https://www.kaggle.com/snapcrack/all-the-news) link:

> The publications include the New York Times, Breitbart, CNN, Business
>   Insider, the Atlantic, Fox News, Talking Points Memo, Buzzfeed News,
>   National Review, New York Post, the Guardian, NPR, Reuters, Vox, and
>   the Washington Post